# Remove LDAP users from Lightdm greeter user list

Tags: login, lightdm, ldap

I have default user accounts which are local to my system and I want to show them in a user selection list. This is working.

Recently, I've enabled logins with LDAP. The flow is selecting "Other..." and inserting the username and password. This is working.

The problem is that the LDAP users stay in the selection list, presumably because their UID is larger than 1000. I want to keep my list of local users but I want that every LDAP stays off the list. How can I do this?